# Using AWS Codestar, how can I make an IAM permission persist between commits/builds/deploys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-codestar

I'm using the Codestar Node.JS Expressjs quick start template. So far I have it to where I can send an HTTP request to the endpoint, and have it write to a DynamoDB database that I created.

Unfortunately, this can only work if I go through the below process; otherwise I get a permission denied error:

1. Commit some code, wait for it to re-build/re-deploy
2. Go into the IAM role for the Lambda function in AWS console web UI
3. Manually add the access permission for my DynamoDB table resource, save, and re-deploy through Codestar

Then, if I commit more code, the modifications I made to the IAM role get overwritten.

I'm guessing this is because those IAM rules get re-generated on each build, but I wasn't able to find anywhere that I can add the resource to make it persist between builds.

Comment: @Eric- Can you please show us the actual error logs? Please follow https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-workshops/tree/master/DevOps tutorial before going forward.

Comment: @kit The permission denied error isn't the problem -- that makes perfect sense. The problem is that the permission I've granted (to let Lambda work with that DynamoDB table) is being overwritten when the new code gets deployed through the Codestar process.